clang++ ignores -fno-exceptions if header is included from -isystem directory
Let's say I have main.cpp that includes utils.h from lib directory:
lib/utils.h:
#ifndef LIB_UTILS_H
#define LIB_UTILS_H

inline void util() {
  throw 13;
}

#endif // LIB_UTILS_H

main.cpp:
#include "utils.h"

int main() {
  util();
  return 0;
}

If I tell clang to search in lib using -I it respects -fno-exceptions:
% clang++ -I lib -fno-exceptions main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:1:
lib/utils.h:5:3: error: cannot use 'throw' with exceptions disabled
  throw 13;
  ^
1 error generated.
%

But if I use -isystem instead of -I it compiles successfully:
% clang++ -isystem lib -fno-exceptions main.cpp
%

And when I try running it, it throws and exception:
% ./a.out
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
zsh: IOT instruction  ./a.out

I checked with Clang 14 and 18, they behave the same. gcc correctly fails to compile in both cases.
Why is -fno-exceptions ignored by Clang?

-isystem says to treat lib as a system include folder.  System headers may contain non-conforming code without generating messages. See System Headers

@RichardCritten But g++ fails to compile even with -isystem lib. Also, the page you referenced only says warnings are ignored in system headers, but using throw with -fno-exceptions is an error, not a warning.

-isystem is for C header files. Have you tried -cxx-isystem?

@3CxEZiVlQ Same thing, compiles with no errors with -cxx-isystem.

2.8 System Headers, Controlling Diagnostics in System Headers. Compilers suppress all compiler warnings in -isystem directories. Clang likely also suppresses errors of using -fno-exceptions.
